# In Spring boot , How to pass the value of a jsp form input in the form action as parameter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I want to pass the input from user as a url parameter like

```
<frm:form action="/myController?parameter=aFormInput" method="POST"></frm:form>
```

I have tried

```
<frm:form action="/myController?parameter=${mAttr.firstname}" method="POST" modelAttribute="mAttr">`
 <frm:input path="firstname">
</frm:form>
```

And i want to fetch this parameter in my controller as

```
@PostMapping(value="/myController" param={"parameter"}) 
public String myMethod(@RequestParam("parameter") String para){}
```

Comment: is it possible or not i dont know

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to write a Request Body element as a parameter.
It's better to use a @RequestBody for your inputs.